# Incorrect print due to HasMorePages

Tags: c#, printing

I am having problems with multi-page printing. I want to print a list of articles by using the method `e.HasMorePages`. *PrintpreviewDialog* shows exactly what I want to print, but when I print, the list hasn't been printed.

#### This is my code:

```
    int Q = 0;
    int Z = 1100;        
    int letter= 13;        
                             



private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        
        int X = 40; int Y = 150;

        //draw text that appear in print preview dialog and print page            

        Y = 180;

        //draw text which appear in print preview dialog and print page

        Y = 210;
        for (int i = Q; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            Q++;                
            //draw text wicih appear in print preview but doesn't in print page
                
            Y = Y + 30;                
            if ((Y >= Z)) 
            {
                e.HasMorePages = true;
                Y = 180;
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                e.HasMorePages = false;

            }
        }
    }
```

This shows PrintPreviewDialog:
[image: printpreviewDialog]

This is the print output:

[image: print output]

Comment: Flagging question because too broad. Try narrowing down the issue in your code. There is too much stuff external to your question in what you've posted (do we really need to see all the `.DrawString` lines?) and not enough included (`.HasMorePages` needs to be troubleshot, with you telling the results of your troubleshooting).

Comment: Sorry @Aaron Thomas, im from Argentina, my english isn't good enough and this is my first post. I think working with e.HasMorePages caused my problem, because One-Page printing doesn't cause problems.